# Run py file with different arguments each time in pyCharm

Tags: python, debugging, terminal, pycharm

I have some script : **run.py**  , I was using it in terminal like :

```
python run.py -t 10 -s adidas -f mozilla
python run.py -t 2 -s nike -f chrome
python run.py -t 100 -s puma -f safari
python run.py -t 1 -s tom
```

but how to live in pyCharm?
I need each time to configure Run/Debug configuration ?
Thanx

Comment: no make a config that has one set of arguments, for each set of arguments and call it `RunNikeSafari` or something and save that configuration(that way you can reuse it) ... or change the arguments to come from somewhere else (csv file or database or hardcoded list etc...)

Comment: Tick **"Show this page"** option in Run/Debug Configuration??

Comment: or.. you could still use terminal in PyCharm (it has built-in one)

Comment: oh yes, i`ve forgot about terminal, thanx!

Answer (score 1):

easiest is to make a runner file

**testrunner.py** (same folder as run.py)

```
import .run
args= [ "-t 10 -s adidas -f mozilla","-t 2 -s nike -f chrome","-t 100 -s puma -f safari"]
for arg in args:
    sys.argv[1:] = arg.split()
    reload(run)
    run.main()
```

or you can use `os.system` to call it with the arguments, but you lose alot of the debugging features of pycharm doing that ...

or alternatively you could make 1 run config for each set of paramaters and save the run config(this is probably how pycharm expects you to do it)

Comment: but i have 1000`s of such combinations, i thought i can in some way parametrizy running a file in pycharm

Comment: In my case, each run consumes a lot of my RAM and for some reason does not release the memory. Memory is released only after the script finishes. So, I can't use a for loop. It would have been nice if PyCharm had a meta run configuration where we can execute existing run configurations in a loop